# Shell Script to read from log file and update to Oracle DB table

Tags: oracle, shell, awk, splunk

I have a requirement to read a splunk log file  for certain parameters and use that data to update an Oracle 11g DB table once those parameters are found.

*for e.g.*

*Splunk log file name is:* `app.log`

*input parameters in log file would be:*

```
[timestamp] amount=100,name=xyz,time=19 May 2018 13:45 PM
```

*output from shell script should be:* amount should be read in to a variable and 100 should be assigned to that. This value 100 should be stored in a DB table in Oracle.

I may have to use awk script for this. I am not getting an idea on this as I am new to shell scripting..

```
tail -f|egrep -wi 'amount' /apps/JBoss/log/app.log
```

This type of commands doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Not clear, could you please elaborate more details on this? If possible with samples of input and output too.

Comment: Edited the question to include some more details @RavinderSingh13.

Answer (score 1):

You may easily capture such values using Perl's regex.

```
amt=$(perl -pe 's/^amount=(\d+).*/$1/' /apps/JBoss/log/app.log)
```

If you want to use pure shell commands,

```
amt=$(grep amount app.log| cut -f1 -d',' | cut -f2 -d '=')
```

You may use this variable in the `insert` query from `sqlplus`

```
sqlplus -s USER/PWD<<SQL
INSERT INTO yourtable(column_name) VALUES(${amt});
commit;
exit
SQL
```

Comment: Thank you.. My requirement changed and have to write it in AWK now

Answer (score 0):

The DB Connect app may the job for you.  See http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/DBX/3.1.3/DeployDBX/Createandmanagedatabaseoutputs.

Answer (score 0):

For an input file (`app.log`) like:

```
[timestamp] amount=100,name=xyz,time=19 May 2018 13:45 PM                
[timestamp] amount=150,name=xyz,time=19 May 2018 13:45 PM                
[timestamp] amount=200,name=xyz,time=19 May 2018 13:45 PM
```

you could use grep's `P` flag (PCRE):

```
arr=($(grep -oP "(?<=amount=)\d+" app.log))
```

This will store the values of `amount` in an array `arr`. Output:

```
echo ${arr[@]}
100 150 200
```